# How to test with views and not windows in Visual Studio 2019 with FlaUI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, flaui

Is it possible to test views with FlaUI?

I have usercontrols with views and tabs on it and not windows.
With windows you can do this:

`Application.GetMainWindow`

But how can I do that with views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

It takes a few seconds to start the application, so I added the following line:

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)`

And if you want to find buttons/labels etc. You have to use this function:

`Window.FindFirstDescendant(cf => cf.ByAutomationId("MyButton"))?.AsButton()`

Answer (score 0):

As usual I create special UI test application project with window and put my view to this window. Then I just call Application.GetMainWindow. It is supposed to create some window to test UI through UI Automation.